# Change merge shortcut?

Tags: mesh, shortcut, topology

I have a High poly mesh and I have decided to make the low poly by merging as it is easiest for me. Would it be possible to change the <kbd>W</kbd> Hotkey , so that it merges to the center automatically? It is time consuming pressing <kbd>W</kbd> *> Merge > Center*.

Comment: Would the decimate modifier work?

Comment: no , This is because im making the low poly have edges which i need  and it dosnt work very well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Blender 2.8x

As of Blender 2.8x the 'Merge at Center' shortcut has been removed so you would have to **create a new one**. *Right-click* <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> the *menu item*, click 'Assign Shortcut' and choose whatever you like:

[image]

*Alternatively* you can add it to the new 'Quick Favorites' list. That way you can access the operator by using (<kbd>Q</kbd>) in the viewport. <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> the *menu item* and select 'Add to Quick Favorites':

[image]

Another option is to **create the shortcut manually**. Go to the *User Preferences > Keymap*, then unfold *3D View > Mesh > Mesh (Global)* and add a custom shortcut item by clicking 'Add New'. Set the identifier to `mesh.merge`, it's type to 'At Center' and the actual key event to <kbd>W</kbd>:

[image]

---

#### Blender 2.7x

As always in Blender *Right-click* <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> the button (*menu item* in this case) and select *Change Shortcut* will do the trick. If you want to reset it, original shortcut (default value) is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> for **all merge methods** (menu items). For this reason you could also disable/remove unnecessary shortcuts in this dialog to prevent that the dialog appears:

[image]

[image]
*Merge At Center (without Dialog)*

Another option is to set the shortcut via **User Preferences** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>). Select the *Input Tab* and *type: merge* in the search area or simply unfold *3D View > Mesh > Merge*:

[image]

Comment: Hey @p2or could you update this for 2.83? `mesh.merge` doesnt seem to exist in the keymap options and `merge`  does not have the `At Center` option.

Comment: Hi! Right, it's now called via mesh menu and can not be edited easily... However, you can either create a new shortcut using `mesh.merge` as described in my answer for 2.7x or just add it to the new quick favorites operator list (`Q`) @BenRacicot

Comment: Hey @p2or actually `mesh.merge` does not seem to exist anymore when searching. Were you able to successfully replicate your answer for 2.83?

Comment: Updated my answer for 2.8x @BenRacicot