# Is there a keyboard shortcut to change the render engine?

Tags: rendering, customization, shortcut

Is there a keyboard shortcut to change the render engine? I have looked through the keymap preferences and I cannot find one. Is there any way to make one?

My computer takes a while to render with the Cycles engine and becomes very slow so it is hard for me to switch back to Eevee using my mouse, so a keyboard binding to switch back and forth between the engines would be very helpful.

If anyone could give me any advice on this is, I would appreciate it very much :)

Comment: If it's not in the keymapping preferences then I don't think it exists.  The only way to really do that would probably be to program something with python.  But Idk

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change merge shortcut?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31092/change-merge-shortcut) (Works for the render engine field too)